# Prevent usesrs from landing on non ajax #! pages on my site without loop and SEO _escaped_fragment trouble

Tags: ajax, redirect, seo

My site is AJAX but it pulls content from .html files. Some of those files have been indexed without the #!, so they just function as a basic html site. I want to redirect users that land on the non ajax page to the #! version. I tried a redirect (without thinking about it) and it created an endless loop with the dynamic content.

If you look at the code, you will see that it uses js to place the static pages into a content wrapper.

I am equally having trouble with an seo issue, where google does not appear to be requesting the escaped_fragment version... that or I need some help. I thought that since it was pulling content from html files, I could just copy those pages and add name it _escaped_fragment_=page.html it is not working. I tried a redirect, but google fetch just showed the redirect request and not content.

It was a template that I purchased... I figured out how to modify the theme and content, but this is beyond me.

Closed

I decided to scrap the hashbang method. I have real pages, and I decided to let them be searched and indexed. I am waiting on a solution to pull only the body into the ajax content warapper; however, I was able to apply basic CSS to the pages without messing anything up when loaded into the main page via ajax.

I used

```
        $("a").attr("href", function(i, href) (some js stuff to add a hash-- hostname +# href)
```

to add a hash to the clean urls that were internal from the main menu. This created a loop if added to the pages, so I used a clean url with an onclick redirect to the ajax version. "/" before the link.

```
onclick="window.location = '/#link.html';return false;"
```

I had a JS redirect that detected if there was a hash before the page link, and if not, added it; however, google did not like it! Sure the pages are not as nice. That said, I have content for non JS enabled browsers. As soon as I get the main.js modified so that it ignores head elements, I can dress them up even more. Each page has links that will get a user to the ajax version, including the home button "/#".

Comment: Could you provide an example of an ajax based url and its equivalent ugly one?

Comment: I decided just to have static pages and hashed pages. It is not as pretty if someone lands on the non ajax page; however, I am trying to figure out how to only fetch the body element so that I can add some styling to the head. I would PM you the main.js, but I do not see that option. All the links on the main page use a simple javascript to add a hash to the internal clean urls.

Comment: I should note that I added a home button to each page that links to /#, and all other internal links have an onclick function to the hashed url. There are only a few lnks that needed hashed on the plain html pages, and the js I used on the index would cause a loop if I used it on the plain pages when loaded as ajax content. I did find an if window.hash code that instantly added the hash, but my page rank jumped off a cliff.